# Vee-Validate: Dependent dropdown with multiple conditions

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate, buefy

I have three dependent inputs ways for my form that requires validation.

1. First Dropdown
2. Second Dropdown
3. Third Free Text

[image: Form]

I need help in implementing the [required_if](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#required-if) condition as the syntax is a bit confusing to make put it to work, and resolve the following

1. When [Issue Category] has the value 'Other (Enter Detail)', then [Issue] needs to be disabled, [Detail] field becomes required.
2. When [Issue] has the value 'Other (Enter Detail)' then [Detail] field becomes required.
3. v-bind:key is required for the second dropdown, but unsure how to use a number to remove the error that appears in the console.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/moyk221x0y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please include the relevant code in your question in the future.  The Code Sandbox is great, very helpful, but on Stack Overflow, the goal is to be able to find answers within the site (not needing to leave it to view parts of the question or answer).

You don't need to use `required_if`.  Instead, use the object form of `v-validate` like so:

```
  <b-input 
    type="textarea" 
    v-model="item.detail" 
    v-validate="{'required':(item.issue_category == 'Other (Enter Detail)')}" 
    name="detail">
  </b-input>
```

For your other problem, it's essentially the same except you also forgot to give the select a `name` which is required.  Also don't mix HTML5 `required` attributes in there, I don't think it helps:

```
          <b-select
            v-model="item.issue"
            name="Issue"
            v-validate="{'required':(item.issue_category != 'Other (Enter Detail)')}"               >
```

That's it!  See a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/x921mkx4qo).

Comment: Thank you, Ryley. I had issues with Buefy working here, but I will keep that in mind next time.

One more issue that I am facing is with the dependent dropdowns. When [Issue Category] and [Issue] value has been selected everything is fine, but once [Issue Category] value is changed, [Issue] value is blank and the validation does not show an error. Any idea on this fix?